# Every several minutes, all my open windows re-adjust their content and text layout

Tags: mac, mojave, mac-mini, performance, displayport

Every several minutes, my computer nearly halts as it all the windows have their content re-adjusted. It seems as though all the text, at least, is being re-rendered. Perhaps the entire window's content (text images etc.) is being laid out all over again. Of course I do not know for sure. All I know is what I see: all the content moving around a bit, several pixels, and then settling down again.

While visually annoying, even worse is that my computer nearly halts. I cannot move windows or choose menus. Often my Apple Magic mouse looses its Bluetooth connection, then reconnects after the window content has stopped dancing around.

This behavior has been going on for months, driving me nuts.

I have never seen this before in any of my many Mac computers.

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on a Mac mini (2018) with a 32" BenQ 4K monitor attached via Thunderbolt 3 (Mac) to DisplayPort (monitor). I used the same monitor with Mojave on a MacBook Pro with no such problem.

In System Preferences > Displays, I have Resolution set to Scaled, with the middle option chosen for "Looks like 3008 x 1692", Rotation is Standard, Underscan is Off, and AirPlay Display is Off.

➥ Any idea what is causing this, and what might be the fix?

I am willing and able to do a clean install and move to Catalina if need be.

I am *not* complaining of "shearing" where either left or right half of the monitor briefly has distortions before re-appearing normally. I know that happens with 4K monitors, something to do with a 4K screen represented internally as a pair of virtual screens as I vaguely recall. With my problem, I can see individual windows taking turns to re-layout their content.

Comment: Make sure you are using the recommended display resolution. Also, try booting Safe Mode so that the Mac checks itself for issues. Let me know how it goes so that if it works, I can add an answer for it.

Comment: @Todd Added text about Displays > Scaled > "Looks like 3008 x 1692" setting.

Comment: I don't know if that is the default. Try Safe Boot. (Restart then hold "Shift")

Comment: Have you tried to add a new user and leave that account without any additional software. Does the problem still occur? If not, I strongly suspect some additional software you have installed is causing this trouble.